# How to subscribe with filters?

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

Is there a way for subscription to receive input filters as parameter similar to queries and mutation?

Currently, my subscription doesn't have a data source and I wanted to only receive subscriptions if this field begins with this value.

**Sample Mutation response**

```
{
  taskId: "personal-<uuid>",
  name: "Personal Task 1",
  ...
}
```

Basically, I only want to have one subscription to check for all task updates where `taskId` `beginsWith` the `String` **"personal"**.

**Schema**

```
input TableStringFilterInput {
  ne: String
  eq: String
  le: String
  lt: String
  ge: String
  gt: String
  contains: String
  notContains: String
  between: [String]
  beginsWith: String
}

input TaskInput {
  taskId: ID!
  ...
}

input TaskFilterInput {
  taskId: TableStringFilterInput
}

mutation updateTask(task: TaskInput) :  Task
subscription onTaskUpdated(filter: TaskFilterInput) : Task
@aws_subscribe(mutations, ["updateTask"])
```

**Test subscription using Appsync's query console**

```
subscription TaskUpdated {
  onTaskUpdated(filter: {
    taskId : { beginsWith: "personal" },
  }) {
    taskId
    name
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/real-time-data.html

You can pass arguments like this

```
subscription TaskUpdated {
    onTaskUpdated(taskCategory: "personal"){
        taskId
        taskCategory
        name
    }
}
```

If it's possible to add another property taskCategory to Task type... might solve your problem.

Your other option is to filter in your app